# Fubinis Theorem for Lebesgue Integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

We have recently learned Fubinis Theorem for Lebesgue Integrals in lecture.

However, I do not see how it is all that useful.
Since in our formulation we consider a function $f$ from $ X \times Y \to [-\infty, \infty]$ to be measurable on that space regarding the product measure of two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$. Furthermore, if $f$ is integrable regarding the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$, than we are allowed to integrate $f$ first in $Y$ and than $X$ or vice versa and end up with the same value for the integral as if we would integrate over $X \times Y$. However, I do not see how one can in practice prove straight forward, that $f$ is integrable on $X \times Y$.

Any tips on how to use the theorem and show the integrability condition would be very much appreciated. (We have not discussed the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem which is more useful in my eyes.)

Comment: Let $f\geq 0$. Then $\int_{X\times Y}f(x,y)(\mu\otimes \nu)(dx,dy) = \int_X\int_Y f(x,y)\nu(dy)\mu(dx) = \int_Y\int_X f(x,y)\mu(dx)\nu(dy)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great question! Recall that a function $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is. But the integrability of $|f|$ can be verified from Tonelli's theorem (the prequel to Fubini).

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that for a function $f\ge 0$, I can use Tonelli's Theorem. If $f$ is any function I should be able to split it into the positive and negative part and use Tonelli separatly for both parts to determine If f is integrable. Is that correct?

Comment: Apply Tonelli on $|f|$ directly instead.